# Create two child process to finish summation of odd and even series

Tags: c, unix, fork

For input of `n = 10`, i am getting a weird output :

```
pid = 31456
Sum of Odd series : 25
pid = 31456
Sum of Even series : 30
pid = 31456
```

Code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t child_pid;
    int i, j, k, n;
    int sum;

    //printf("Enter the last number of series : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("pid = %d\n", getpid());

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid < 0)
        {
            printf("Failed to create child process . . .");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (child_pid == 0)
        {
            if (i == 0) //find the sum of odd series
            {
                sum = 0;
                for(j = 1; j <= n; j += 2)
                    sum += j;

                printf("Sum of Odd series : %d\n", sum);
                exit(0);
            }
            else if (i == 1) //find the sum of even series
            {
                sum = 0;
                for(j = 2; j <= n; j += 2)
                    sum += j;

                printf("Sum of Even series : %d\n", sum);
                exit(0);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            wait(&child_pid);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ideone link : [ideone.com/TyIkJa](http://ideone.com/TyIkJa)

Comment: When you use `fork`, all data from the parent process is _copied_ into the child process : when you write in `sum` in your children processes, it's not going to be propagated back to the parent's `sum`, as each child process will use its own version of this variable.

Comment: eww, well then what is the proper way to handle such issues ?

Comment: fork makes a copy of the process, So once you exit children, the children die along with the calculated values which are local to them. If you want to read values from children, you have to use pipes or shared memory.

Comment: i have updated the code & the output, can anyone tell if why `pid = 31456` is being executed three times, afaik, the code below `fork()` is only executed multiple times.

Comment: @AppDeveloper - Please do proper edit of your question. People will downvote my answer after they look at your edited question. I am getting pid=31456 only once when I run the same code.

Comment: @vishram0709 - ohk, will keep that in mind while editing, well, on ideone.com link its showing 3 times.

Comment: @AppDeveloper - Please use this **fflush(stdout);** after printing pid. This will clean the buffer and it solves your problem.

Comment: `fork()` is just not the right tool for the job, consider programming this with threads.

Comment: @JensGustedt - i agree, but it is a assignment question, i missed my unix classes due to illness and now i am suffering !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change your code as below.

```
if (childs[i] == 0)
    {
        if (i == 0) //find the sum of odd series
        {
            for(j = 1; j <= n; j += 2)
                sum += j;
            printf("Sum of odd series : %d\n", sum); 
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (i == 1) //find the sum of even series
        {
            for(k = 2; k <= n; k += 2)
                sum += k;
            printf("Sum of even series : %d\n", sum);  
            exit(0);
        }

else
    {
        wait(&childs[i]);
    }
```

The reason is both children and parent have their own copies of sum. So when you are ending the parent still has sum=0 ,but these values are updated for "sum" of child1 and "sum" of child2.

Answer (score 0):

When you fork a process, then parent and child are initially 
more or less exact copies, including the values of variables, 
 except for the return code of fork().

But the key word there is copies. 
Those two processes are now independent and variables, 
"global" or not, **are not connecte**d in any way.

Comment: Please you proper formatting while you write answers and be specific while you answer.